# How to identify the Oracle SID or Service Name on Oracle Server Database on Azure

Tags: oracle, azure

I have created an Oracle Server and Database on Microsoft Azure.

I have used Oracle before.

Can someone take a look at the attached image and let me know how to get either the SID or the Service Name on an Orcale Server / Database in Azure

[image]

Comment: how do you not know the db name/sid if you created the database?

Comment: Please understand @OldProgrammer, I have never ever built an Oracle Server/Database before. Therefore, I have absolutely no idea at which point I would have created a SID.

Comment: Also, you need to remember that this Oracle Server was built on MS Azure, and not how you might typically build an Oracle Server/Database

Comment: Just so you the image is taken from attempting to connect with dbForge Studio for Oracle.